# Avoid adding breadcrumb if title is empty

Tags: views, 6, breadcrumbs

I created a view without the title but then the breadcrumb shows  as

Home>  >

If I add title to the view then it is showing as

Home> >Title

is there any way to avoid adding breadcrumb when empty title is present ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can remove the breadcrumb if you create a template for the view:

views-view--your-view-name--page.tpl.php

Comment: Nice idea, I L try to do that.

Comment: Solution: I was previously using the development version of Token module, now just updated the module with the stable version. Thats the simple solution!!!